# PHP CMS with the ability to have multiple block on one page

Tags: php, content-management-system

I am looking for a PHP CMS that gives me the ability to assign different blocks to different parts of the template. The website has multiple pages that on each page the content is broken up into different blocks, but each page design is different from the previous.

So I am looking for a CMS that will let me design each in HTML/PHP, and then in a certain area I can say load block content from id=X.

Does anyone know if a CMS that would allow me to do this?

Comment: ModX can do this easily - it's called "Chunks" there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [Drupal](http://drupal.org/about), which is written in PHP/HTML to be highly configurable for that exact thing.  I would suggest using the [Zen](http://drupal.org/project/zen) theme because it allows you to configure many sub-themes or "child" themes so that each page can have it's own design.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at CMS Made Simple ([www.cmsmadesimple.org](http://www.cmsmadesimple.org)).  You'll probably need to add the "AdvancedContent" and "CGSimpleSmarty" modules to do exactly what you want but I do this kind of thing all the time with it.

Answer (score 0):

I am with you on this! It is the thing I hate most about every CMS out there. They all only allow you to edit a single main portion of each page. The best I've done to remedy this is to use Wordpress then theme it in such a way that I keep the content that will change the most within the loop portion of the code as I design a theme then hardcode every other part and hope it won't change too often. I'll have to look into modx because I like that chunk idea. I'm starting work on my own seriously simple CMS that allows for "chunks" or blocks. The world doesn't need yet another CMS but it sure needs more that have this feature.